# An error occurred for port: FabricProvider

Tags: java, soa, weblogic11g

I am getting below error while i test my BPEL(SOA 11g) application on Weblogic . Please provide some inputs if you guys have encountered this before. Thanks

[2014-03-15T16:42:34.885+11:00] [AdminServer] [ERROR] [OWS-04115] [oracle.webservices.service] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: ] [ecid: 11d1def534ea1be0:6e87597f:144978f1d1e:-8000-00000000000efee7,0] [APP: soa-infra] [composite_name: ExecuteEligibilityFlowControllerBPEL**] **An error occurred for port: FabricProvider: javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException.****

**Complete Logs--**

[2014-03-15T16:42:34.828+11:00] [AdminServer] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.wsm.agent.WSMAgent] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Defau
lt (self-tuning)'] [userId: ] [ecid: 11d1def534ea1be0:6e87597f:144978f1d1e:-8000-00000000000efee7,0] [WEBSERVICE_PORT.name: EligibilityManagementPort
Type_v1_pt] [APP: soa-infra] [composite_name: ExecuteEligibilityFlowControllerBPEL] [component_name: ExecuteEligibilityFlowController] [component_instance_id: 7
0501] [J2EE_MODULE.name: fabric] [WEBSERVICE.name: EligibilityManagement-v1] [J2EE_APP.name: soa-infra] Message Type is normalized, exiting agent.processFault()
[2014-03-15T16:42:34.828+11:00] [AdminServer] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.wsm.agent.WSMAgent] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Defau
lt (self-tuning)'] [userId: ] [ecid: 11d1def534ea1be0:6e87597f:144978f1d1e:-8000-00000000000efee7,0] [WEBSERVICE_PORT.name: EligibilityManagementPort
Type_v1_pt] [APP: soa-infra] [composite_name: ExecuteEligibilityFlowControllerBPEL] [component_name: ExecuteEligibilityFlowController] [component_instance_id: 7
0501] [J2EE_MODULE.name: fabric] [WEBSERVICE.name: EligibilityManagement-v1] [J2EE_APP.name: soa-infra] Message Type is normalized, exiting agent.processFault()
[2014-03-15T16:42:34.872+11:00] [AdminServer] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.wsm.agent.WSMAgent] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Defau
lt (self-tuning)'] [userId: ] [ecid: 11d1def534ea1be0:6e87597f:144978f1d1e:-8000-00000000000efee7,0] [WEBSERVICE_PORT.name: EligibilityManagementPort
Type_v1_pt] [APP: soa-infra] [composite_name: ExecuteEligibilityFlowControllerBPEL] [J2EE_MODULE.name: fabric] [WEBSERVICE.name: EligibilityManagement-v1] [J2EE
_APP.name: soa-infra] Message Type is normalized, exiting agent.processFault()
[2014-03-15T16:42:34.872+11:00] [AdminServer] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.wsm.agent.WSMAgent] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Defau
lt (self-tuning)'] [userId: ] [ecid: 11d1def534ea1be0:6e87597f:144978f1d1e:-8000-00000000000efee7,0] [WEBSERVICE_PORT.name: EligibilityManagementPort
Type_v1_pt] [APP: soa-infra] [composite_name: ExecuteEligibilityFlowControllerBPEL] [J2EE_MODULE.name: fabric] [WEBSERVICE.name: EligibilityManagement-v1] [J2EE_APP.name: soa-infra] Message Type is normalized, exiting agent.processFault()
[2014-03-15T16:42:34.872+11:00] [AdminServer] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.integration.platform.blocks.tenant] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: ] [ecid: 11d1def534ea1be0:6e87597f:144978f1d1e:-8000-00000000000efee7,0] [WEBSERVICE_PORT.name: EligibilityManagementPortType_v1_pt] [APP: soa-infra] [composite_name: ExecuteEligibilityFlowControllerBPEL] [J2EE_MODULE.name: fabric] [WEBSERVICE.name: EligibilityManagement-v1] [J2EE_APP.name: soa-infra] NM or Event does not contain property, apps.context.header or fabric.enterpriseId
[2014-03-15T16:42:34.884+11:00] [AdminServer] [ERROR] [OWS-04086] [oracle.webservices.service] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: ] [ecid: 11d1def534ea1be0:6e87597f:144978f1d1e:-8000-00000000000efee7,0] [APP: soa-infra] [composite_name: ExecuteEligibilityFlowControllerBPEL] javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException[[
        at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.soap.WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.generateSoapFaultException(WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.java:1345)
        at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.soap.WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.processIncomingMessage(WebServiceEntryBindingComponent.java:968)
        at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.soap.FabricProvider.processMessage(FabricProvider.java:113)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.provider.ProviderProcessor.doEndpointProcessing(ProviderProcessor.java:1187)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.WebServiceProcessor.invokeEndpointImplementation(WebServiceProcessor.java:1112)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.provider.ProviderProcessor.doRequestProcessing(ProviderProcessor.java:581)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.WebServiceProcessor.processRequest(WebServiceProcessor.java:233)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.WebServiceProcessor.doService(WebServiceProcessor.java:194)
        at oracle.j2ee.ws.server.WebServiceServlet.doPost(WebServiceServlet.java:485)
        at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.soap.FabricProviderServlet.doPost(FabricProviderServlet.java:528)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
        at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
        at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

]]
[2014-03-15T16:42:34.885+11:00] [AdminServer] [ERROR] [OWS-04115] [oracle.webservices.service] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: ] [ecid: 11d1def534ea1be0:6e87597f:144978f1d1e:-8000-00000000000efee7,0] [APP: soa-infra] [composite_name: ExecuteEligibilityFlowControllerBPEL] An error occurred for port: FabricProvider: javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException.
[2014-03-15T16:43:15.691+11:00] [AdminServer] [WARNING] [] [oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.TreeRendererUtils] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: 11d1def534ea1be0:6e87597f:144978f1d1e:-8000-00000000000eff2c,0] [APP: em] Context menu child is not a RichMenu
[2014-03-15T16:43:29.426+11:00] [AdminServer] [WARNING] [] [oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.TreeRendererUtils] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: 11d1def534ea1be0:6e87597f:144978f1d1e:-8000-00000000000eff53,0] [APP: em] Context menu child is not a RichMenu
[2014-03-15T16:44:43.492+11:00] [AdminServer] [WARNING] [] [oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.TreeRendererUtils] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: weblogic] [ecid: 11d1def534ea1be0:6e87597f:144978f1d1e:-8000-00000000000effc6,0] [APP: em] Context menu child is not a RichMenu